# ActionScript assignment operators, what does >>>= mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

On the Adobe ActionScript page link below, there is a list detailing Operator Precedence. It includes the following:

```
= *= /= %= += -= <<= >>= >>>= &= ^= |=
```

What do the <<= >>= >>>= assignments mean?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1

Comment: The list of all operators with descriptions (including those you asking about) and examples is here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html

Comment: @fsbmain I see no reason why you didn't post this statement as answer?

Comment: OK, I'll do, to have that question answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `Bitwise compound assignment` operators, you can find descriptions with examples in [AS docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_left_shift_and_assignment)